# How to send and render an .html for chromecast using RAW http requests?

Tags: deobfuscation, javascript

I am trying to RE the chrome cast protocol.
I saw Koushik Dutta did RE the [protocol](https://plus.google.com/110558071969009568835/posts/G3jF2JynLc2), but didn't find any post online analyze the protocol. Moreover Google changed it a little bit since then.

currently I figured out some of the http packets the sender and receiver transmit but I would like to figure out what is the http request I need to send the cast device in order it will render an .html file and/or javascript code on it.

---

I want to mimic [this snippet](https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world) without using google API nor `APP ID` nor `NAMESPACE`:

```
 $(function() {
        var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver('*** YOUR APP ID ****', ['*** YOUR NAMESPACE ***']),
            channelHandler = new cast.receiver.ChannelHandler('*** YOUR NAMESPACE ***'),
            $messages = $('.messages');

        channelHandler.addChannelFactory(
            receiver.createChannelFactory('*** YOUR NAMESPACE ***'));

        receiver.start();

        channelHandler.addEventListener(cast.receiver.Channel.EventType.MESSAGE, onMessage.bind(this));

        function onMessage(event) {
            $messages.html(event.message.type);
        }
```

I want to find the right `curl` / `http` request in order to run my `.js` on the cast without using google API. for example the following [curl](http://fiquett.com/2013/07/chromecast-traffic-sniffing/):

```
curl -H “Content-Type: application/json” http://10.0.1.2:8008/apps/YouTube -X DELETE
```

kills the running app on the cast. How can I make it run my app without being bounded to google's whitelist and demo API.

The google [cast_reciver.js](https://www.gstatic.com/cast/js/receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js) is obfuscated:

```
cr$rb = function (a) {
    cr$k(a, "Listener can not be null.");
    if ("function" == cr$b(a)) return a;
    cr$k(a.handleEvent, "An object listener must have handleEvent method.");
    return a[cr$Ab] || (a[cr$Ab] = function (b) {
        return a.handleEvent(b)
    })
};
```

Comment: that is you're asking for a recipe, not for the answer to a specific problem you encounter, right? I think you need to break it down into separate questions then. It appears too broad.

Comment: so, you want to know how to deobfuscate the receiver JS ?

Comment: @0xC0000022L I edited the question and made it to be more specific. thanks